# how to extract data from joomla website into csv file

Tags: form

Users enroll for courses on my website. I want to know how to extract that information into a flat file (csv file)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL own the tool MySQLDUMP you car use in CLI comand on yoour server. You can have more explanations on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/dump-all-tables-in-csv-format-using-mysqldump

With all the parameter on this command, you can recreate a valid CSV file

Comment: thank you. I do not have a server